# IOS Validate/Submit to ITunes Connect Fails

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-push-notifications, app-store-connect, itunes

i tried validate my app to Itunes but it failed with this error

[Itunes Validate Error picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx2FuCLhvkaoRVZnb1ozQWF0WTg/view?usp=sharing)

"Missing or Invalid signature . the Bundle 'My app ' at bundle path 'Payload/the.app' is not signed using Apple Submission Certificate."

i try create new certificate and new provition profiler  tried to revock certificate and create new one and create new Provisioning Profiles
and still the same error

my app use push notification  so i tried disaple it and create  new cert/profile    for app store
and still on the same error

can anyone help me please ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to validate the app and submit it using another mac , problem may be caused by my mac or by Xcode 6

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not using the correct distribution Certificate and Provision on your project. Click on your target and go to **Build Settings**.

Search for Code Signing Identity and see if it's using the **iPhone Distribution:Your Company** identity on the "Identities on Keychain" popup.

Also leave the **Provision Profile** field set to Automatic.

Comment: i set debug  to iphone Developer and release to IPhone Distribution
i olso try to set profile in debug to developmrnt and  release for Distribution for both project and target 
all of that makes no different

Comment: You should be asked for the profile when archiving and exporting. Can you see the available profiles there?

Comment: no after select email it show the summary and then the error

Comment: i just create new fresh empty app with new cert/profile and create new app in itunes with the new Bundel Identifier and Archive it , when try to validate i get the same Error also i try o Export app and submit using Application Loader  with the same Error

Comment: As Apple docs explains, it's related to your provision. I don't know how you are generating it, but something is broken... You will need to take a look on the build log, specifically on the code signing part... Go through each of those steps and see if it works: [TN2318](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2318/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013777-CH1-TNTAG0)